# how to call after_commit(inject by sunspot) asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I'm using sunspot with rails.
I know sunspot will use the `after_commit` hook to re-index...
But if ever `after_commit` fails, the transaction rolls back and the `Account(ActiveRecord::Base)` I want to save is deleted.

I want to use sidekiq, `perform_async`to call the `after_commit` hook, but don't know how I can do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    module Reindex
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      def async_reindex
        AsyncIndexJob.perform_later(self.class.to_s, self.reload.id)
      end

      included do
        after_save :async_reindex
      end
    end

    class AsyncIndexJob < ActiveJob::Base
      queue_as :index

      def perform(*args)
        obj = args[0].constantize.find_by_id(args[1])
        if obj
          Sunspot.index obj
          Sunspot.commit
        end
      end
    end
```

1.include Reindex module in ActiveRecord::Base

2.set :auto_index => false

3.all done

[AsyncIndex](https://github.com/MoonShining/AsyncIndex)